# Modifying "style" of .docx TOC using javascript (docx-js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, docx

**Question:**

Following this tutorial, https://docx.js.org/#/usage/table-of-contents, I would like to do the following two things:

1. Change the font & size of entries in the table as the default `Times New Roman - 10` is too small.
2. Remove the "leading dots" from entries to page numbers:
   `a.......1` to `a       1`

**What I tried (with no success):**

1. All my entries are based on `Heading1` so their level is 1. `stylesWithLevels: [new StyleLevel("Style", 1)]`. This produces no change whatsoever.
2. `entryAndPageNumberSeparator: "\t"` gives leading dots (`a.......1`), while `entryAndPageNumberSeparator: " "` gives `a 1`. I tried other combinations like `entryAndPageNumberSeparator: " \t"` to no avail. It seems like only the first character is taken into consideration.

Both of these were tested individually with a working TOC (*modified from the above tutorial*):

```
new TableOfContents("Example", {
  hyperlink: true,
  headingStyleRange: "1-1",
}),
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to the part (1) of your question? I am trying (unsuccessfully) to set different styles per level.

Comment: related?: https://github.com/dolanmiu/docx/issues/435#issuecomment-835805064

Answer (score 0):

I know the question isn't recent, but I just spent 3 hours trying to solve this problem, and I finally found the solution. Maybe it will be useful to someone!

There are two separate topics here:

1. Changing the text style:
   stylesWithLevels does not update the text style. You need to create a style like TOC1 and modify it; it will be applied to the first level of the table of contents. TOC2 for the second level, and so on.

```js
paragraphStyles: [
    {
        id: "TOC1",
        name: "toc 1",
        basedOn: "Heading1",
        next: "Heading1",
        quickFormat: true,
        run: {
            color: "000000",
            size: 40,
        },
    },
]
```

2. Removing the "point" separator between the text and the page number:
   To do this, you need to modify the paragraph's tabulation in which the table of contents is located:

```js
new Paragraph({
    children: [
        new TableOfContents("Summary", {
            hyperlink: false,
            headingStyleRange: "1-1",
            entryAndPageNumberSeparator: "\t",
        }),
    ],
    tabStops: [
        {
            type: TabStopType.RIGHT,
            position: TabStopPosition.MAX,
            leader: TabStopItem.NONE
        },
    ],
})
```